# Diferença entre Server Object Explorer e Server Explorer

Tags: c#

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida com vocês. Uma dúvida que não consegui resposta em lugar nenhum. Queria saber a diferença entre o **Object Explorer** e o **Server Explorer**.

Essa dúvida surgiu depois que segui aquele tutorial da Microsoft onde fazem uma aplicação para uma universidade fictícia. Eu fiz todo o processo e, no meio do tutorial, dizem que caso eu não use uma *connection string*, o *Entity* se encarrega de criar uma *default*. Dito e feito. Executei a aplicação sem *cs* e rodou. 
Editei, excluí registros sem problema sem mesmo ter criado uma *cs*. 
A questão que eu queria entender é o fato de, depois de dar o *run*, eu só conseguir visualizar a base de dados no **Object Explorer** e não no **Server Explorer**. Por que essas duas ferramentas existem juntas? Não seria necessário só uma? Quem puder esclarecer essas dúvidas, eu ficaria muito grato!

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o Server Explorer ao que você se refere é o [SQL Server Object Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272693(v=vs.103).aspx), certo?

O Server Explorer é um componente do Visual Studio que lista servidores em geral, não apenas de bases de dados. Ele pode listar servidores de outras coisas, como Azure e SharePoint.

O SQL Server Object Explorer é outro componente que lhe permite acessar servidores especificamente de bases de dados do SQL Server, da Microsoft. Ele é mais específico e especializado.

Ambos listam somente servidores que você tenha adicionado de alguma forma. Você pode adicionar o seu servidor ao Server Explorer, por exemplo... Clique com o botão direito sobre "Data Connections", e em seguida clique em "Add Connection...". O Visual Studio abrirá uma tela na qual você poderá escolher o tipo de provider e em seguida uma tela para se inserir endereço e credenciais.

Eu nunca usei o SQL Server Object Explorer, mas suponho que não seja muito diferente.

Uma coisa legal a se fazer agora é experimentar tudo que você pode fazer com ambos os componentes, comparar as diferenças e ver qual lhe agrada mais. Mas pessoalmente, se é para trabalhar com SQL, eu prefiro utilizar outra ferramenta. O [SQl Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/mt238290.aspx) te dá muito mais controle sobre suas bases de dados.